# Error while reading XML file

Tags: java, xml

I got an error while trying to read this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job>
    <id>B002</id>
    <name>Name</name>
    <time>every day 1:00</time>
</job>
```

It said:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///D:/JobManagement.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 20; A pseudo attribute name is expected. .

I searched on google and find out some ways to solve this problem but they did not work. I'm using SAX Parser code from Mykong.com in the following link :

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

I have to solved this as quick as I can so I do not have enough time to learn it. Please help me.
Above xml code is just part of my file.

```
public class JobManagementService {
public void ReadXMLFile() {

        try {

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

                boolean bfname = false;
                boolean blname = false;
                boolean bnname = false;
                boolean bsalary = false;

                public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
                        throws SAXException {

                    System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("FIRSTNAME")) {
                        bfname = true;
                    }

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LASTNAME")) {
                        blname = true;
                    }

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("NICKNAME")) {
                        bnname = true;
                    }

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("SALARY")) {
                        bsalary = true;
                    }

                }

                public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

                    System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);

                }

                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

                    if (bfname) {
                        System.out.println("First Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        bfname = false;
                    }

                    if (blname) {
                        System.out.println("Last Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        blname = false;
                    }

                    if (bnname) {
                        System.out.println("Nick Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        bnname = false;
                    }

                    if (bsalary) {
                        System.out.println("Salary : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        bsalary = false;
                    }

                }

            };

            saxParser.parse("D:\\JobManagement.xml", handler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

I call ReadXMLFile method here

```
@GetMapping("/jobManagement")
public String home() {
    jobManagementService.ReadXMLFile();
    return "/jobManagement";
}
```

I just want to test this function before applying it

Comment: where is the code that you use for parsing the file

Comment: @Prashant I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

The file you have shown us is well-formed and parseable. Because the error message is very precise about what is wrong and where (just after the `version="1.0"`) my suspicion would be that one of the characters isn't what it appears to be. Perhaps the quotation marks are actually "smart quotes", or perhaps the space after `version="1.0"` is actually a non-breaking space.

(By the way, telling us you are in a hurry and don't want to investigate the problem thoroughly will put many people off from answering your question. We're problem-solvers by nature, we like to get to the bottom of things, and working with someone who says they don't want to put any effort in from their side is not usually very rewarding.)

Comment: Oh, Im sorry. But I'm under too much pressure. I change it from .xml to .txt and it worked

Comment: If changing the file extension worked, my guess would be that you have some kind of configuration issue perhaps with the web server that's serving the document and/or with character encodings. You may have found a workaround, but you haven't solved the problem.